# Lotus Domino 8.5.3 Running Compact via CLI

Tags: ibm-domino

I have Lotus domino Email Server 8.5.3 FP6.
My question is can I run compact -a (and once the archive is done it should run compact -B) from command prompt on running domino (in off peak time, without stopping the domino services ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which DBs you wish to run the command. What I normally do is to use a program Document to periodically run a server command as written [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21088932). And read also [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_RUNNING_COMPACT_USING_A_PROGRAM_DOCUMENT_3190_STEPS.html) if you wish to compact something. Both require that the server is online, otherwise the program document will not kick in. You couldn´t compact for example the admin4.nsf while the adminP task is running, but mail DBs should be working. I have done that multiple years.